# How to catch errors using Sequelize's findOrCreate()

Tags: node.js, error-handling, sequelize.js

It seems I can only use the `.spread(user, created)` function and not the `.error()` function. I'm getting validation errors when trying to insert non-unique entries for testing and it's killing my node process.

How can I catch errors from `findOrCreate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can catch errors in the following way:

```
User
  .findOrCreate({where: {username: 'sdepold'}, defaults: {job: 'Technical Lead JavaScript'}})
  .spread(function(user, created) {
    //...
  }).catch(function(error) {
    //handle error
  });
```

The `.catch` handler is available for all Sequelize operations, as far as I know.